# Can't understand this clojure make-adder example

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to read up a bit on Clojure, but I hit a brick wall with the following basic example:

```
(defn make-adder [x]
  (let [y x]
    (fn [z] (+ y z))))
(def add2 (make-adder 2))
(add2 4)
-> 6
```

What I don't understand is how is `add2` passing the number 4 to the make-adder function, and how does that function turn assigns that number to z.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`make-adder` returns a function that takes one parameter (z), the parameter passed in to `make-adder` is used to assign a value to y. `add2` is set equal to the result of evaluating `make-adder` with a parameter of 2. So `add2` is set equal to the function returned from `make-adder`, which (since y has been assigned to the parameter from `make-adder`) looks like

```
(fn [z] (+ 2 z))
```

So `(add2 4)` calls this function which evaluates to 6. Does that help?

Comment: I don't think the let is even needed it just complicates the code

Comment: About let bindings @Kevin I agree with you that if you're not doing something with the let binding, it does complicate the code. I used them to print out values. I don't need to that as much now, but let bindings do help while learning, and if you need to keep data around in a main loop.

Comment: I just mean in this particular case it was innecessary and confused more than helped. Obviously let is generally useful and has its place.

Answer (score 3):

To me, it seems you are working on an interesting problem.

Your example make-adder function (rewritten without let bindings)

```
(defn make-adder [x]
  "Returns a function that returns the sum of x and yet to be supplied z."
  (fn [z] (+ z x))))
```

returns a function that sums x and z, where make-adder has to have already been called with a value. I believe your example is implementing the Clojure partial function, which is pretty cool.

Here is your make-adder function rewritten to sum its two parameters, and not return a function (so we can use partial in add2),

```
(defn make-adder
  "Returns sum of x and y." 
  [x y] 
  (+ x y))
```

and here is add2 rewritten using partial with 2 as the x parameter:

```
(def add2 (partial make-adder 2))
```

If I call `(add2 2)` the answer is 4, `(add2 3)`, the answer is 5 and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation. I'm quite new to clojure yet, and thus I'm not familiar with the `partial` concept. Wich is why it's a bit hard for me to completely understand your example.